# Difference between Dojo domClass.add() and dojo.addClass()

Tags: javascript, web, dojo

Dojo's official doc for [addClass](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/addClass.html) says

> When using AMD format in a fully baseless application, add is accessed from the dojo/dom-class module.

```
require(["dojo/dom-class"], function(domClass){
    // Add a class to some node:
    domClass.add("someNode", "anewClass");
});
```

What is meant by "fully baseless application"?

and

> Alternatively, you can load dojo base in AMD style and continue using dojo.addClass in the define or require callback:

```
require(["dojo"], function(dojo){
    // Add a class to some node:
    dojo.addClass("someNode", "anewClass");
});
```

What exactly is the difference between `domClass.add()` and `dojo.addClass()`?

Why would one want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

There Is no Difference between these functions :

In the new AMD (dojo version >= 1.7 )
it's recommended to use the `dojo/dom-class` `.add() function`

and in older version  `dojo.addClass` is used

When he said fully baseless application this means when using only this module ( no widget , no special class ) in your app you've to us it without loading all dojo module ,

The main thing Here to know is that 
`dojo.addClass` use itslef the `dojo/dom-class` `.add() function`

You can see in the source of ( [html.js](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/b769bdc730d65aff8e83ac001b1edce1410b97ce/_base/html.js#L113)) , when mixin diferent dojo function

`dojo.addClass = cls.add;` where  `cls` refere  to `../dom-class`, in the define [imported](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/b769bdc730d65aff8e83ac001b1edce1410b97ce/_base/html.js#L1) module  ,

So >=1.7 use directly `dojo/dom-class`